# docker compose throwing econnrefused

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While accessing DB it threw me an error that.

> MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

How to fix it? So my application can make a connection to the database. As in code, you can see my application is relying on multiple databases. how can I make sure before starting the application all of the database containers got started.

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  appnetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    restart: always
    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=11999966
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=interview
      - MYSQL_USER=interviewuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=11999966
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./migration/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    networks:
      - appnetwork
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536  
    volumes:
      - elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - appnetwork
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - cache:/var/lib/redis
    networks:
      - appnetwork
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo:/var/lib/mongo
    networks:
      - appnetwork
  app:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - elasticsearch
      - redis
      - mongodb
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - appnetwork
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: npm start
volumes: 
  db:
  elastic:
  cache:
  mongo:
```

Comment: Where do you configure the location of the database?  Can you edit the question to include this detail, and also reduce the Compose setup to a [mcve] (do you need a non-`default` network, or a `command:` override, or MySQL or Redis containers, to demonstrate the issue)?

Answer (score 0):

The container (probably `app`) tries to connect to a mongodb instance running on `localhost` (i.e. the container itself). Since there is nothing listening on port `27017` of this container, we get the error.

We can fix the probelm by reconfiguring the application running in the container to use the name of the `mongodb`-container (which, in the given `docker-compose.yml`, is also `mongodb`) instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

If we have designed our app accoring to the [12 factors](https://12factor.net/), it should be as simple as setting an environment variable for the container.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer can you please give me yaml file with changes?

Comment: Also one thing I am not able to access the application inside the docker itself but able to access MongoDB from outside the docker

Comment: I cannot provide the `docker-compose.yml` since I do not know the application code. It might be necessary to modify the code to either hardwire the database host to `mongodb` or pull it from some environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://mongo:27017` as connection string instead.